# laplace beltrami and standard laplace operator

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, inequality

let $u\in W^{2,2}(B^+_R)$. Can i conclude that $\vert \Delta u\vert\leq \vert \Delta_g u\vert$ where $g$ is a Riemannian metric?

Best regards

Comment: I don't think so. Just consider $g=(1/2)(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$. Then $\Delta_g=(1/4)\Delta$. Similarly you could shrink the metric arbitrarily, and the Laplace-Beltrami operstor will also shrink arbitrarily.

Comment: What's $B^+_R$?

Comment: $B_R^+$ is the upper ball, i.e. $B_R^+:=B_R\cap \left\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x^n\geq0 \right\rbrace$ with center 0.